# 'linker command failed with exit code 1' error appear again after xcode restarting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

There are many questions about 'linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)' error.

I have solved it a few times. Removing 'library search path', delete and add again libraries(Admob, Flurry).

[image: Error01]

After that it works fine.

However, the key point of my problem is the error occurs again if I restart xcode. Solve it again and do some job. On the next day, the error occurs again...

The condition is xcode 5.1.1 & OSX 10.9.3 & iOS 6.1 7.1 simulator

Comment: may be you are missing to add `target dependency` and you are using the target/framework created in `Derived Data` for linking to current target.

Comment: "linker command" failure are very general. They mean the project points to something that does not exists at that point. Usually, this (as I believe in this case) is caused by 3rd party frameworks. Make sure you added all the frameworks correctly (i.e. Google for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved by
'Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)' option checking.

I have thought that framework and libraries don't need to copy option, and it worked well before. But in this time, it doesn't.